# How to repeat wrong inputs in one block without having to use nested loop?

Tags: java, while-loop, nested, try-catch, repeat

Is it possible to repeat more than one try-catch statements in one block without creating another (nested) while loop or having to repeat the whole loop again?

For example:

```
while(true) {
    //try-catch 1: if the user input is correct continue, or ask him to repeat this input
    //try-catch 2: if the user input is correct continue, or ask him to repeat this input
    break; //after it's done
}
```

Another Ex:

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            try {
                System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
                scan1.next();
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                //do something to repeat this task
            }

            try {
                System.out.println("Enter another number: ");
                scan2.next();
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                //do something to repeat this task
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of working code that you want to rewrite without a nested loop?

Comment: Extract the prompt to a method?

Comment: Sure, just a minute @Blorgbeard

Comment: I added another Ex. @Blorgbeard

Answer (score 0):

The flow you are describing doesn't require *nested* loops, but it does require two separate loops.

I think you want something like this:

```
Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);

while (true) {
    try {
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        scan1.next();
        break;
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {            
        System.out.println("Error! That wasn't a number!");
        // didn't reach a break statement, will repeat.
    }
}

while (true) {
    try {
        System.out.print("Enter another number: ");
        scan2.next();
        break;
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {            
        System.out.println("Error! That wasn't a number!");
        // didn't reach a break statement, will repeat.
    }
}
```

Notice that this is a lot of repeated code, so you could improve it by extracting a method to call - something like:

```
private static int getNumber(String prompt, Scanner scan) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.print(prompt);
            return scan.nextInt();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Error! Try again.");
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);

    int num1 = getNumber("Enter a number: ", scan1);
    int num1 = getNumber("Enter another number: ", scan2);
}
```

Disclaimer: my Java is rusty, so the above code may not be exactly right, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: What I was trying to say from using these two inputs is that they are not separate. They are based from one another(I was trying to give a less complicated Ex). So, after he insert the first input, he goes to the second input that it is build on his first input and so on..

Answer (score -1):

Here  is a simple example where the application will not continue unless there is a valid number supplied.

```
public class TestInput
{

  public static boolean validInput(Scanner scan)
  {
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    try
    {
      String stringNumber = scan.next();
      try
      {
        int myInt = Integer.parseInt(stringNumber);
      }
      catch (NumberFormatException e)
      {
        System.out.println("No I meant a Number; " + stringNumber + "  is not a number");
        return false;
      }
    }
    catch (InputMismatchException e)
    {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }


  public void doTheWork()
  {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    if (!validInput(scan))
    {
      doTheWork();
    }
    System.out.println("All Good");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    TestInput testInput = new TestInput();
    testInput.doTheWork();
  }
}
```

Here is a simple example to reuse a method to get multiple inputs

```
public class TestInput
{
  public static int getNumberInput(String message)
  {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    try
    {
      System.out.print(message);
      String stringNumber = scan.next();
      try
      {
        return  Integer.parseInt(stringNumber);
      }
      catch (NumberFormatException e)
      {
        return getNumberInput("No I meant a Number; " + stringNumber + "  is not a number");
      }

    }
    catch (InputMismatchException e)
    {
      //do something to repeat this task
    }
    return getNumberInput(message);
  }

  public void doTheWork()
  {
    int oneParam = getNumberInput("Enter a number: ");
    int twoParam = getNumberInput("Enter another number: ");

    System.out.println("Your first input is " + oneParam);
    System.out.println("Your second input is " + twoParam);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    TestInput testInput = new TestInput();
    testInput.doTheWork();
  }
}
```

Comment: Still, its only good for one input, just like using while loop. However, he would have repeated the whole process if he got false in the "second input".

Comment: @bad Updated the second example , the user will not continue on unless the  current input is valid. The process will not be repeated

Comment: could you explain how it's different from using while loop to repeat?

Comment: It accomplishes exactly the same as a while loop, in this case I am using method recursion.

Comment: Recursion is a terrible solution to this problem.